# error adding value to list entity (LINQ C#) MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am getting error in adding the value to `IEnumerable` type entity. Here is the `restaurant` entity

```
public virtual ICollection<BusinessUser> BusinessUsers { get; set; }
```

Here is the `businessUser` entity

```
public virtual ICollection<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
```

Here is the action method to add business user to the restaurant

```
public ActionResult Add(Restaurant restaurant)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        restaurant.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        restaurant.BusinessUsers.Select(c => c.PersonID) = 2; // i want to assign the user with id 2 to this restaurant
        db.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["Success"] = "New Restaurant has been added successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(restaurant);
}
```

I see the following error in my editor:

> Only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: @ssilas777 only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: restaurant.BusinessUsers.First().PersonID == 2; is this what you trying to do?

Comment: @ssilas777 yes but i want to set the restaurant business user to 2 and save it to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a `BusinessUser` entity with `PersonID = 2` and attach it to the context (to avoid that it gets duplicated in the database). Then add this entity to the `restaurant.BusinessUsers` collection:

```
public ActionResult Add(Restaurant restaurant)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {    
        var businessUser = new BusinessUser { PersonID = 2 };
        db.BusinessUsers.Attach(businessUser);

        restaurant.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        restaurant.BusinessUsers.Add(businessUser);

        db.Restaurants.Add(restaurant);
        db.SaveChanges();

        TempData["Success"] = "New Restaurant has been added successfully";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(restaurant);
}
```

I assume that `restaurant.BusinessUsers` is instantiated, otherwise add the line `restaurant.BusinessUsers = new List<BusinessUser>();` before adding the user to the collection.

Comment: i want to assign restaurant business user as the current user logged in, i have got the userID.
your code is adding the business user but i want to assign the current business user logged in to the restaurant.

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: The code does this exactly. It doesn't add an existing user to the database, it only creates a relationship between restaurant and your logged in (and already existing) user.

Comment: it is creating the new entity "businessUser"

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: Does the `restaurant.BusinessUsers` collection already contain a `BusinessUser` entity when you enter the `Add` action? If yes, try to add `restaurant.BusinessUsers.Clear();` before `restaurant.BusinessUsers.Add(businessUser);`.

Comment: still the same error, it is giving error on the actual BusinessUser entity properties with Required Attribute

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: Do you mean that `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false`?

Comment: no it is giving "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: password" from the entity BusinessUsers

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: At which line of the code do you get this exception?

Comment: at this line db.BusinessUsers.Attach(businessUser);

Comment: still the same error, it is checking all properties of BusinessUser entity, some of properties of that entity is with Required Attribute and it is giving error only with that properties

Comment: at this line db.BusinessUsers.Attach(businessUser);

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: OK, then try to load the user from the DB instead of attaching a stub, i.e. replace the two lines `var businessUser = new BusinessUser { PersonID = 2 }; db.BusinessUsers.Attach(businessUser);` with the line: `var businessUser = db.BusinessUsers.Find(2);`. Then all required props should be filled.

Comment: now it is giving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at line "restaurant.BusinessUsers.Add(businessUser);" right after the replaced lines

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: Add `restaurant.BusinessUsers = new List<BusinessUser>();` before that line - as said at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time, it worked perfectly, can u please tellme my mistake?? i shall be very gratefull

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: Your initial error `Select(...) = 2` is just illegal C#. `Select(...)` always returns a collection if type `IEnumerable<T>` and you cannot assign a value of `T` to such a collection. The last error "Object reference not set..." (`NullReferenceException`) is pretty common and happens if you try to access any object that is `null`. You must ensure that it is *not* `null` before you access it. More details are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Thanks again, can u please tellme the best professional learning resources for entity framework, linq and MVC 4? please

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: http://www.pluralsight.com/ It's not free but worth the money, especially for beginners. They offer a free trial for a few days if you like to test it first. They have a lot of courses about all 3 topics, for example: MVC4: http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building, LINQ: http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/linq-fundamentals, EF: http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/entity-framework5-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your syntax error is coming from this line:

```
restaurant.BusinessUsers.Select(c => c.PersonID) == 2;
```

Which should probably be something like:

```
restaurant.BusinessUsers.Add(db.Persons.Where(c => c.PersonID == 2).First());
```

Comment: i don't want to compare the values. i want to set the value

Comment: That is exactly what this code is doing. It selects the user with Id 2 and assigns it to `restaurant.BusinessUsers`. try it.

Comment: you are right but i want to select the user i just want to set the restaurant business user to the business user with the id 2

Comment: Then use the approach @Slauma proposes, attach the object with the right ID to the context and assign the object.

Comment: i want to assign restaurant business user as the current user logged in, i have got the userID.
Slauma code is adding the business user but i want to assign the current business user logged in to the restaurant.